# Redirecting Service Fabric URL's

Tags: redirect, azure-service-fabric, azure-application-gateway

I have deployed APIs on Service fabric behind the reverse proxy feature so my frontend application is available at https://something.anything.com:19081/Applicationtype/servicename. I want it to be routed behind a subdomain such as https://app.companyname.com. So to summarize when I hit https://app.companyname.com on the browser I want the landing page of the SF application without the port and trailing paths. What are my options on Azure and how to configure?
Note: As per my research it might be possible via Application gateway but not sure about the configuration.

Comment: Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55579678/5946937

Answer (score 0):

yeah, i think it should be possible with application gateway. you'd need to configure http listener for application gateway to listen on specific hostname and route to specific backend\path combination.

this setup is more or less covered by this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-create-url-route-portal

Comment: i tried it but it gives me "404 service fabric service not found" error when i hit the application gateway host.

Comment: i suppose you need to pass host header as well

Comment: i want to try passing headers but i cant find the option in the UI. Is that capability available only available for certain regions? i am using UkSouth.

Comment: its called hostname under listener configuration. its supported everywhere

Comment: Yes i tried that did not work. I was talking about this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers

Answer (score 0):

The reverse proxy provided by Service Fabric is not very flexible for these scenarios.

A good alternative for you is using [Traefik](https://blog.techfabric.io/using-traefik-reverse-proxy-for-securing-microservices-on-azure-service-fabric/):

> Traefik has a built-in Service Fabric Provider that will query the Service Fabric Management APIs to discover what services are running in the cluster. The provider then maps the routing rules to these service instances.

In you case, you have to define the rules in your services as labels in the service definition, so Traefik can discover the services and use the right rules:

```
<StatelessServiceType ServiceTypeName="WebServiceType">
  <Extensions>
      <Extension Name="Traefik">
        <Labels xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2015/03/fabact-no-schema">
          <Label Key="traefik.frontend.rule.example">PathPrefixStrip: /product</Label>
          <Label Key="traefik.expose">true</Label>
          <Label Key="traefik.frontend.passHostHeader">true</Label>
        </Labels>
      </Extension>
  </Extensions>
</StatelessServiceType>
```

This is a visual representation provided from the docs:

[image: Traefik]